# Access UIView width at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In Swift, how do I get the width (or height) at runtime, of a UIView  that's created programmatically using auto layout constraints?

I've tried `view1.frame.size.width` and `view1.frame.width`, but both return `0`.

I've been following an auto layout tutorial by [MakeAppPie](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/) and added `view1.layer.cornerRadius = view1.bounds.width/2` as below, but this had no effect, so I did a po on  `view1.bounds.width` and got `0`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func makeLayout() {

    //Make a view
    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    //Make a second view
    let view2 = UIView()
    view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)

    //Add the views
    view.addSubview(view1)
    view.addSubview(view2)


    //--------------- constraints

    //make dictionary for views
    let viewsDictionary = ["view1":view1,"view2":view2]

    //sizing constraints
    //view1
    let view1_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view1(>=50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let view1_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view1(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    view1.addConstraints(view1_constraint_H)
    view1.addConstraints(view1_constraint_V)

    //view2
    let view2_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view2(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let view2_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view2(>=40)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    view2.addConstraints(view2_constraint_H)
    view2.addConstraints(view2_constraint_V)

    //position constraints

    //views
    let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-100-[view2]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-136-[view1]-100-[view2]-100-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllTrailing, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V)

    view1.layer.cornerRadius = view1.bounds.width/2

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
    makeLayout()

    }
}
```

Comment: view1.frame.width should work.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: thanks for the reply Steve - have added the code above.

Comment: You're getting 0 there, because the auto layout mechanism did not already kick in at this point to resize your views.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Add this and you are good to go:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        println(self.view1.frame.size)
    }
```

you can look at width or height as you please.

Comment: This also prints out 0,0 for me.

Comment: @kakubei I found that the problem for me was when calling the class initialiser i forgot to actually pass the frame in thus returning 0,0 in the class initialization. XCode didnt give any error for this either.

Answer (score 14):

Just one thing about these fields:

```
self.view1.frame.size.width
self.view1.frame.size.height
```

Are only actual user device size if the view has been drawn to screen, else they are what ever you set them as in the storyboard. So if your trying to perform some kind of calculation before the view is drawn you will have to figure out the width or height another way!

Comment: and what is the way? When in Xcode 7 and below, I had no issues with it. But now in Xcode 8, I get issues with this. My UIImageView size is printing 500, however I think it is barely size 50.

Answer (score 7):

you can only use this

```
self.view1.frame.size.width
self.view1.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 5):

Frame width and height returns zero because at the time you called that function inside of viewDidLoad it is not yet sized properly. You can use viewDidAppear to call your necessary functions