# UIView get width/height without UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have this:

```
class SheetView: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    RCTLogInfo("SHEET VIEW INIT'ED")
    let width = String(format:"%.3f", Double(self.frame.size.width));
    let height = String(format:"%.3f", Double(self.frame.size.height));
    RCTLogInfo("Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height);

  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

However width and height are always 0. Reading here [Access UIView width at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26578234/1828637) it seems I need a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but a `UIView` doesn't seem to have this. I have to use `UIViewController` to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, however I cannot change from `UIView`, because the place this component gets used, expects a `UIView`:

```
class SheetViewManager : RCTViewManager {

  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return SheetView();
  }

}
```

Is there anyway to get height/width in just the `UIView`?

Comment: You have to pass a frame in to `init(frame:)` if you want it to have a non-zero fame.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell for your help, I am very new to Swift, may you please edit my code to show it. Because I do have a `frame: frame` in my `init` call above.

Comment: @Noitidart No you don't. You are calling `SheetView()`, not `SheetView(frame: someNonZeroFrame)`.

Comment: FYI - You don't need any of those semicolons in Swift.

Comment: And change the return value of your `view()` function from `UIView!` to just `UIView`. Avoid needless uses of `!`.

Comment: Thank you very much @rmaddy for all that help, your tips to a Swift newbie like me is very helpful! What does that `!` do anyways?

Comment: I strongly urge you spend lots of time reading the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language) book, especially anything related to optionals.

Comment: I'd say avoid `!` anywhere in your app when avoidable.

Comment: Thank you @cloudcal I am actually a react native guy, and just copying what tutorials are doing. Im not sure why they put that `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you sure can. Try this . (Swift 3.0)

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
  print(self.frame)
}
```

Make sure you know that if your custom view's superview doesn't give your custom view a frame either by frame setting or by autolayout via storyboard or programmatically, your frame will remain at 0 width and 0 height

Comment: Oh my gosh so perfect! Thank you sir! I actually am very new to Swift I really appreciate your help. My view is a view in React Native. So it has a dimensions set from javascript and I needed to access it on the other side in a responsive way. This is triggering on portrait to landscape transform too. Superb! Thanks again sir!